# How to express "still others", as in "some people do X, others do Y, still others do Z"

Tags: expressions, énumération

In English, you say "some ..., while others ...", when comparing just two groups of people. And when the third group is thrown into the mix, you add "still" or "yet" to "others":

> ***Some*** people do X, ***others*** do Y, ***still***/***yet*** ***others*** do Z.

The same construction applies to the German equivalent as well:

> ***Manche*** von uns {Some of us} ..., ***andere*** {others} ..., ***wieder andere*** {again others} ...

The French equivalent eluded me, though, when I  was saying the following sentence. All I could come up with as a quick-fix on the spot was « il y en a qui ... », but this is not strictly in the same vein as the English and German equivalents:

> ***Certains*** de nos patients de l'étranger choisissent ..., ***d’autres*** préfèrent ..., et ***il y en a qui*** ...

What is a commonly used French expression for the third group "still others"?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Si seulement trois cas sont traités, votre proposition, ainsi qu’une version similaire à votre exemple en allemand et une troisième mentionnée ci-dessous par *qoba* sont très courants¹ :

> - Certains [...], d’autres [...], et il y en a qui [...].
> - Certains [...], d’autres [...], et d’autres encore [...].
> - Certains [...], d’autres [...], et d’autres enfin [...].

Si davantage de cas sont cités, il y a plusieurs possibilités. Pour offrir de la variété, on peut s’inspirer des exemple triviaux qui suivent, ou en construire un à sa guise :

> - **Certains** adulent Astérix, **d’autres** lui préfèrent Tintin, **d’autres encore** sont enthousiasmés par Spirou, **il y ceux pour qui** il n'y a que Thorgal et Aaricia qui vaillent la peine et **ceux qui** ne sauraient se passer des interminables discours d'Achille Talon, **et finalement il y a Feelew,** qui SAIT que Gaston Lagaffe est le meilleur de tous.
> - **Certains** aiment le riz, **d’autres** préfèrent les pommes de terre, **d’autres encore** ne jurent que par les pâtes, **il y ceux qui** prônent le couscous et **ceux qui** ne sauraient se passer de fèves rouges, **sans oublier** les fanas du tofu **ni** les amateurs de quinoa **ou** les inconditionnels du sarrasin, **ainsi que ceux qui finalement** aiment la variété et choisiront parmi tous ces mets selon l’inspiration du moment.

Si certains groupes peuvent être identifiés en particulier, par exemple *« ceux qui n’aiment pas un certain ingrédient d’une recette »* ou *« ceux qui doivent utiliser le transport adapté »*, on pourra directement les introduire tels que mentionnés ici, ce qui permettra d’allonger la liste sans tomber dans la redondance.

> **Certains** ajouteront des noix concassées ou des amandes en tranche, **d’autres** des raisins secs ou de pépites de chocolat, **ceux qui en ont les moyens** substitueront du sirop d'érable au sirop de maïs et **ceux qui préfèrent leurs desserts moins lourds** pourront réduire de moitié la quantité de beurre indiquée.

---

> *¹ La première phrase elle-même pourra à la rigueur être un autre exemple de trois items mutuellement exclusifs énoncés à la suite :*
>
> - *Votre proposition*
> - *ainsi qu'une version similaire...*
> - *et une troisième*

Comment: I'm sorry: I forgot to answer in English. Are you ok with the French version, or would you rather have it translated?

Comment: Hi. Oh, French is completely fine for me. ;) I used to write my questions in French, but now make a point of sticking to English, so that even beginners in French who are currently hard pressed to wade through French text can take full advantage of what this site has to offer.

Comment: Another vote for "d'autres encore" which seems to me the closest to the original.

Comment: "d'autres encore" ou "d'autres enfin" (si l'énumération se conclue au troisième)