# Is this the best way to say some... others?

Tags: choix-de-mot, constructions

> Certaines personnes riches veulent plus de l'argent, mais d'autres sont des philanthropes. Certaines personnes pauvres veulent plus de l'argent, mais d'autres s'en moquent.

I'm using *certaines ... mais d'autres* to form my construction, but I am not sure whether this is the best way to go about it. How would you form this construction?

Feel free to correct my French!

Comment: To expand on this point further: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/26037/how-to-express-still-others-as-in-some-people-do-x-others-do-y-still-other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Certain[e]s***...**mais d'autres** is fine although *mais* isn't required, but your sentences need some work.

*Personnes* is unnecessary, *riches* and *pauvres* can be used as substantives.

*Plus de l'argent* should be *(encore) plus d'argent* or *s'enrichir*

*Sont des philanthropes* works, but better to use it as an adjective *sont philanthropes*

> *Certains riches veulent encore plus d'argent* (or *veulent s'enrichir encore plus*)*, d'autres sont philanthropes.*

Similarily:

> *Certains pauvres veulent s'enrichir, d'autres s'en moquent.*

Comment: Merci beaucoup! Would certains... d'autres be your first choice for this construction? Are there any other succinct, viable alternatives?

Comment: Yes, *certains... d'autres...* would likely be my first choice.